# How to unsort a np array given the argsort

Tags: arrays, numpy

I intially have an unsorted np array of arrays

```
test = np.array([['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A'],
       ['B', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'B'],
       ['C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C'],
       ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
       ['B', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'E'],
       ['C', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'D']])
```

To sort the array based on the first column:

```
argsortTest = test[:,0].argsort()
test_sorted = test[argsortTest]

  test_sorted:  
[['A' 'A' 'B' 'E' 'A']
 ['B' 'E' 'A' 'E' 'B']
 ['B' 'D' 'A' 'C' 'A']
 ['B' 'A' 'E' 'A' 'E']
 ['C' 'D' 'D' 'A' 'C']
 ['C' 'D' 'C' 'E' 'D']]
```

I make some processing over `test_sorted` array changing some values (the first column remains intact and the number of rows unchanged). In the end I want to retrieve the orginal array of arrays keeping the changed values. So I need to 'unsort' it again based on first column

My solution so far:

```
argsortTestList = argsortTest.tolist()
rangeX = np.array(xrange(6))
unsort_args = [argsortTestList.index(x) for x in rangeX]
unsorted = test_sorted[unsort_args]
```

The reason I do sort and then unsort in the end is because I got better performance when working on the sorted array. However as the changes done are not reflected in the original array, I have to unsort it again.

However the 'unsorting' solution is too slow (large dataset: around 200K rows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do

```
b = np.argsort(argsortTest)
test_sorted[b]

# Output
# array([['A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A'],
#        ['B', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'B'],
#        ['C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C'],
#        ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
#        ['B', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'E'],
#        ['C', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'D']], 
#       dtype='|S1')
```

**Explanation**

Consider the following array

```
comb = np.column_stack((np.arange(argsortTest.size),argsortTest))
comb

# array([[0, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [2, 3],
#        [3, 4],
#        [4, 2],
#        [5, 5]])
```

The left column are the indices of `test` and the right the result of `argsort`, this means the index `0` goes to `0`, `1` to `1`, `2` to `3`, ... Since the first column is sorted we can simply use advanced indexing in order to get the ordered array `test[argsortTest]`.

Now, you want to do the inverse, i.e. go from the right column to the left such that the index `0` goes to `0`, ... `4` to `3`, `2` to `4`, ...
In order for advanced indexing to work for the left column the right column must now be sorted

```
comb[np.argsort(comb[:,1])]

# array([[0, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [4, 2],
#        [2, 3],
#        [3, 4],
#        [5, 5]])
```

But since this left column is exactly the `argsort` of the right column in `comb` we find that

```
test = test_sorted[ np.argsort(argsortTest) ]
```

I hope this helps in order to understand the idea ...